# How to correctly code a microsoft word labels mail merge to omit data from the rest of the page?

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word, mailmerge

Ok, so we have a process that we use to create shelf labels at a store. Basically, we have a excel CSV file that holds text. All cells within the range are formatted as straight text. The fields are as follows:

ITEM NUMBER

RECEIPT ALIAS

SIZE

RETAIL

ITEM ID

ORD QTY

PROMO PRICE

Basically, part of the label to show the a certain price. If the PROMO PRICE column is blank (empty), it should show the RETAIL. Otherwise, it should show PROMO PRICE. I have that much worked out using an IF formula in word which is:

{ IF { {PROMO_PRICE} = "" {RETAIL} {PROMO_PRICE} } }

Now, this works well and returns the data that I need. The actual word document (mail merge file) is formatted to return 18 labels per page (3 rows of 6) and works from the top right corner down, then middle top down, then left top down.

So, here is the problem I'm having: Let's say I only have 3 rows of data in the CSV file (3 items that need labels). The rest of the rows are blank (verified by selecting like 200 rows and deleting just to be safe). The first 3 labels show the correct data (PROMO PRICE if there is one, else RETAIL), BUT the rest of the labels should be blank...instead, they are showing the last printed price (regardless of whether it is a PROMO PRICE or a RETAIL. For example, I have 3 labels that all have multiple lines of data on them (item #, receipt alias, size, and retail or promo price). The last item (label) has a RETAIL of $1.69 (directly from the CSV file). The other 15 labels should be completely empty/blank, but instead, they show the $1.69 price! They show none of the other data fields except for the IF formula's result of the very last label...

Some important notes that might be helpful:

1) The formula result for the last label only persists through the rest of the labels on that page (i.e. it's not like it's recognizing an infinite number of rows in the CSV file, therefore it can't be an issue with the CSV file...it has to be the Mail Merge word document)

*******EDIT********

I seem to have found some more information that may be useful in helping me figure this out. The formula will work and not fill the resulting page of labels as long as it returns the "" in the last case. In other words, the mail merge document's last page of results is duplicating the results of my very last IF statement (so it's duplicating the results of the last row of the CSV file)...

Any ideas?

Comment: the problem may be with this part `{PROMO_PRICE} = ""`. Perhaps test for `Null` instead. Also, try suppress blank fields option (it's called something like that.) Or you could create this formula in an excel column and just reference that field in your mail merge. That's actually probably the easiest way to work around it.

Comment: I thought using = "" is the same thing as testing for Null? I've made an updated edit to my post above. I don't know how the suppress blank fields would help since it's basically applying the IF statement to all blank rows of data based on the last row of data in the CSV file...

Comment: Please show us the exact field code in these labels.

Answer (score 0):

Bibadia, thanks so much for the information! That seems to have been my issue the entire time! I changed the code to:

{ IF { {**MERGEFIELD** PROMO_PRICE} = "" {**MERGEFIELD** RETAIL} {**MERGEFIELD** PROMO_PRICE} } }

This correction now only shows the data I want for excel rows in my database that actually have data in them! Now, I won't waste full pages of labels! Thanks so much!